# arm_kinematics_constraint_aware dies after call to get_fk

Tags: ros-fuerte, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using autogenerated custom `lwa_arm_navigation` stack acquired from [Planning Description Configuration Wizard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard) on Fuerte. Arm is the 7 DOF Schunk LWA provided within [care-o-bot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/care-o-bot) stack.

When calling `/lwa_arm_kinematics/get_fk`, a node adopted from [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%203) tutorial returns error:

```
Forward kinematics service call failed
```

and `arm_kinematics_constraint_aware` node dies with the following error:

```
[lwa_arm_kinematics-5] process has died [pid 12417, exit code -11, cmd /home/0xff/ros/arm_navigation/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/bin/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware __name:=lwa_arm_kinematics __log:=/home/0xff/.ros/log/0f7bc99c-024c-11e2-8d0d-c860005ffb62/lwa_arm_kinematics-5.log].
log file: /home/0xff/.ros/log/0f7bc99c-024c-11e2-8d0d-c860005ffb62/lwa_arm_kinematics-5*.log
```

Although this problem looks exactly same as [on Electric](http://answers.ros.org/question/10765/electric-get_fk-forward-kinematics-fails-simple-test/) provided solution does not work anymore. So is it a problem of different nature in my case?

Request to `get_fk` is filled as:
`fk_request.header.frame_id = "base_link";
fk_request.fk_link_names.push_back("arm_7_link");
for(unsigned int i=0; i < response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names.size(); i++)
{
fk_request.robot_state.joint_state.position[i] = 0.0;
}`

The kinematic chain is:
`$ rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf lwa.urdf
robot name is: lwa
---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
root Link: base_link has 1 child(ren)
child(1):  arm_0_link
child(1):  arm_1_link
child(1):  arm_2_link
child(1):  arm_3_link
child(1):  arm_4_link
child(1):  arm_5_link
child(1):  arm_6_link
child(1):  arm_7_link`

However `/lwa_arm_kinematics/get_fk_solver_info` saying there is only one link -- `arm_7_link`

Thanks in advance for any help

---

EDIT#1:

Here is the output from `gdb`

`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffe0fce700 (LWP 27607)]
0x00007ffff7ddd39a in std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::operator=(std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void > const&) ()
from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libsensor_msgs.so
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install
<--- a lot of package names here --->
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Thread 0x7fffcb7fe700 (LWP 27647) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffcbfff700 (LWP 27639) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe0fce700 (LWP 27607) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe17cf700 (LWP 27606) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe23db700 (LWP 27596) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe2bdc700 (LWP 27595) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe33dd700 (LWP 27594) exited]
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.`

---

EDIT#2:

I am not good at debugging with plain `gdb` so I did it with the help of Eclipse. So the cause of SIGSEGV is here:

`bool
ArmKinematicsConstraintAware::getPositionFK(
kinematics_msgs::GetPositionFK::Request &request,
kinematics_msgs::GetPositionFK::Response &response){
// --- cut --- //
if(!collision_models_interface_->convertPoseGivenWorldTransform(
*state, request.header.frame_id, world_header,
poses[i], response.pose_stamped[i])) {
response.error_code.val = response.error_code.FRAME_TRANSFORM_FAILURE;
return true;
}
// --- cut --- //
}`

Here **`poses`** and **`response.pose_stamped`** has different size, while the counter runs based on **`poses.size()`** which is 1, the **`response.pose_stamped`** is empty.

Now, the question is it a bug or I should initialize `response` fields by myself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44135/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware-dies-after-call-to-get_fk/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-09-19**:
Could you investigate a bit more, when exactly (at which line) the node dies? You can use [GDB via roslaunch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) to do a backtrace.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-19**:
Are the joint names filled in the robot_state in the request? (nevertheless, the node shouldn't abort)

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-20**:
@dornhege, yes, same as in tutorial: `fk_request.robot_state.joint_state.name = response.kinematic_solver_info.joint_names;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am still not sure is it a bug or not, but with this patch it works

`--- a/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/src/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware.cpp    2012-09-20 19:57:27.443296318 +0900
+++ b/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/src/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware.cpp   2012-09-20 19:58:20.796409267 +0900
@@ -339,6 +339,8 @@ bool ArmKinematicsConstraintAware::getPo
request.fk_link_names,
poses);
if(valid) {`

- response.pose_stamped.resize(request.fk_link_names.size());
- response.fk_link_names.resize(request.fk_link_names.size());
  for(unsigned int i=0; i < poses.size(); i++) {
  std_msgs::Header world_header;
  world_header.frame_id = collision_models_interface_->getWorldFrameId();

---

EDIT #1:

Opened a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5567) for the bug.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-09-20**:
First, if the above works for you, great! However, I have the feeling this patch is not the right way to solve your problem. I took a look at the code snippets you mentioned and indeed couldn't find a line, which adjusts the size of pose_stamped. You say, the node crashes ...

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-09-20**:
in the call to "convertPoseGivenWorldTransform()". Could you find out at which line in this method the node dies? If in the end, we find no other cause of this crash and an according fix, I recommend sending in your patch via a bug ticket.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-09-20**:
It dies on the first line inside `convertPoseGivenWorldTransform()` during assignment of `ret_pose.header = header`. That's may be because there is no boundary check on STL vectors when assign with index.